# My web site is a blank page now

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to view my website but all what I get is a blank page .
When I try to log into it with my Wordpress , I get nothing and I'm sure that my user name and password are correct. I can't even log into FileZilla.
the only thing that I can log into is http://ns1.petunia.arvixe.com/
 I've googled a lot but nothing 
I'm still a beginner so if you please tell me what to do in a little details. Thanks.

Comment: Check your error logs. This looks like the famous "white screen of death" - it just means that there is a fatal error and you have display_errors set to off. Check your error logs for the actual error, we can't help you any more than tell you to look at them.

Comment: Try to set debug on true in your wp-config.php file.

Comment: I'm really sorry but could you please tell me in steps how to do so , I'm still a beginner , Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. Disable all your plugins at once.

Open your FTP client and navigate to /wp-content/plugins and rename the folder "plugins" to "plugins_old".

Refresh wordpress or try to access /wp-admin/

2. Debug WordPress

In your FTP client, edit wp-config.php and add the following code:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Refresh the page and wordpress will now show errors.

3. .htaccess problems

In your FTP client, rename .htaccess to .htaccessOLD. Refresh the wordpress site and look if its working. If not, try to access /wp-admin/. If you see the login page, login, and reset your permalinks to regenerate a .htaccess file.

To reset your permalinks go to Settings > Permalinks > and change them to default.

3.1 Default .htaccess

Open up the .htaccessOLD file;

Your .htaccess should look something like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /nieuw/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

If it doesn't, rename is back to .htacess (without old) and copy paste the code above and save.

Refresh the wordpress site.

NOTE: Before step 3 make sure you edit wp-config.php and edit

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

to

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

otherwise it will probably show errors.

Comment: I did exactly what you said but as soon as I renamed plugins to plugins_old and my site now is crashed and all what I get is this message :   
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found. I'm ready to give you my user and password but please help me .

Comment: Rename it back to plugins. But did you debug it?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply . Yes , I did and renamed it again to plugins

Comment: Sure mail me your login details and I'll take a look for you @ info@michael-vermeulen.nl I might need ftp info. You can create a new ftp login and set permissions to the wordpres folder only.

Comment: Thanks a gain Michael Vermeulen I'm sending you now what you asked

Comment: No problem Islam Gaber, i know how it feels when WordPress screws up.

Comment: I fixed your website by disabling a certain plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved . Thanks to  Michael Vermeulen 
The problem was caused by the following plugin: coming-soon-maintenance-mode-ready
wich is now deactivated and now every thing is OK